# Select Radio Button if click anywhere on row in Angular 5

Tags: html

I have prime ng table having 2 columns one is for radio button and the other is for name.I just want to select the radio button if click anywhere on the row.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is various primeng table versions ! Could you add code sample?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any script for this - if you associate the text with the input using a label, this works out of the box... in the example below you can click on the radio, or the "Radio Button Label".

```
<div>
    <label for="test">Radio Button Label</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="test" name="test" />
</div>
```

Comment: Actually we did not have label for the radio button So I used
<input type="radio" name="selectRoom" [checked]="rowIndex === checked" (change)="setSelectedRoomData(rowData,rowIndex)" />

Comment: So wrap this inside empty label element :) Fenton method works very good